# How does exercise cause weight loss if the corresponding chemical reactions have the same mass on the LHS and the RHS?

Tags: metabolism, energy-metabolism, exercise

How does weight loss take place in the body during physical activity, given that the corresponding chemical reactions would have the same mass on the left hand side and the right hand side?

Comment: What chemical reactions would these be? We cannot answer question if you don’t specify the problem.

Comment: Please give example of chemical reactions you're referring to, It will help us answer your question.

Comment: Better yet, look *yourself* at the reactions and think about what might happen to the products...

Comment: I don't know what chemical reactions take place. I just remember studying years ago that the metabolic activity in the body is basically chemical reactions. And chemical reactions don't involve a change of mass between LHS and RHS is another thing I remember studying. So how does weight loss take place then (apart from sweat and bodily waste being expelled from the body)?

Comment: This is a layman question -- I have no knowledge of biology or chemistry beyond high school level which was years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excretion. You've really answered your question in your own comment, except that you don't seem to have realized that there is no "apart from sweat and bodily waste being expelled from the body".

Simplistically, say the body has some stored fat, which has the general formula CH3(CH2)nCOOH.  When you exercise, the fat is burned for energy, converting it to CO2 and H20.  The CO2 is exhaled, the H20 leaves either as perspiration or urine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_metabolism#Lipid_catabolism

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.